# matplotlib crosshair cursor in PyQt dialog does not show up

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt, cursor

I want to have a crosshair at the cursor in my `matplotlib` window. This works out in the example, given in the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/cursor.html). But unfortunately, it does not work if I have the matplotlib widget in a Qt dialog window (`QDialog`).

This is my sample of code, where I want to instantiate the `matplotlib.widgets.Cursor` object, but nothing shows up.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor

class Window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.figure = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        ''' plot some random stuff '''
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax = ax
        ax.plot([1,2])

        # Set cursor        
        Cursor(self.ax, useblit=False, color='red', linewidth=1)
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified your code as follows and it works on my computer. Hope it helps.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor

class Window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.figure = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        ''' plot some random stuff '''
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax = ax
        ax.plot([1,2])
        # Set cursor        
        cursor = Cursor(self.ax, useblit=False, color='red', linewidth=1)

        ############## The added part: #############
        def onclick(event):
            cursor.onmove(event)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
        ############################################
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The original code in (1): `Cursor(self.ax, useblit=False, color='red', linewidth=1)` doesn't leave a reference to the Cursor as indicated in the documentation.

The code in (2) has the assignment, but not to a class reference but to a local variable:

`cursor = Cursor(self.ax, useblit=False, color='red', linewidth=1)`

The code in (2) works with the indicated additions but the cursor move slowly.

The solution is the code as in (1) but modified as follows:

`self.cursor = Cursor(self.ax, useblit=False, color='red', linewidth=1)`